# Creating a Python 3.6 virtual environment without installing Python 3.6

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.6

I have openSUSE 42.3 with Python 3.4.6 installed, and since upgrading my Python 3 installation to 3.6 is risky, I want to create a virtual environment that I can later use with PyCharm IDE.

What's the proper way of doing that, without actually upgrading my Python version?

Comment: You have to install a new interpreter and tell `virtualenv` to use that.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using `conda`, which manages *different python versions for you*.